Best Practices for ROS2 GUI?
When developing a GUI for a ROS application, what is the best practice to interface many nodes and their information to a single GUI?
Is it best to have a GUI node that just reads and publishes topics related to the input to the GUI and all other nodes are listening to those topics? Or is it best to try to keep all ROS processing on one node that has a GUI?
Is having multiple a separate thread for the GUI and a separate thread for the ROS2 node processing beneficial?

I have been implementing GUIs using Pyside and PYQT using QT designer. If there is a good example of code that uses the pyside6 generated python code for the GUI - would sure love to check it out!

I love using https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler which in some sense is a GUI and it's OpenSource, so possibly a good code-read for pointers.
